# Ghosted Vs UnGhosted pages sharepoint2007

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

Can anyone tell me the difference between ghosted and Unghosted pages?
Which is the best option to go for while creating a site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghosted pages are pages whose content doesn’t reside in the content database  they reside on the actual file system disk. When site pages are customized, the page is unghosted and their content is then stored in the content database. The issue with unghosted pages is that site maintenance and performance can be affected (e.g. updating server or solution may be impacted or site caching may be affected).

A better outline is given here

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/tools/article.php/c9581/